# convert rdfxml into turtle triples

Tags: java, rdf, semantic-web, sesame

I've written a java program that ingests data from a .csv, and converts those data into RDFXML. I used [sesame's](http://rdf4j.org/) framework when writing this program, and the program successfully does what it was written to do.

However, I am trying to unit test this program using jUnit, and I need to test a method which converts RDF triples (in turtle format) to RDFXML. To show that the method works correctly, I would like to do this by converting RDFXML back into triples and comparing them to the original triples I passed into the method. So far, I have not found anything in [sesame's](http://rdf4j.org/) documentation does this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you just want to write the data in TTL as opposed to RDF/XML?  How do you write the data in RDF/XML (code, please :))?

Comment: I actually just figured it out. It turns out that I didn't need to rewrite it in TTL at all. I just needed to parse the RDFXML file with an RDFXMLParser, and that ingests the statements without issue. I'll post my solution below.

Comment: For future reference, Sesame's Rio parser/writer toolkit is documented [here](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#Parsing_and_Writing_RDF_with_Rio) . It actually includes a code examples showing how to convert from one format to another.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem a few minutes ago. Here's my solution:

```
@Test
public void testWriteStmtToRDFPos(){
    RDFParser parser = new RDFXMLParser();
    String baseURI = "";
    Model origStmts = new LinkedHashModel();
    Model processedStmts = new LinkedHashModel();
    StatementCollector collector = new StatementCollector(processedStmts);
    parser.setRDFHandler(collector);
    origStmts.add(sexOffend,predicate,object);

    try{

        converter.writeStmtToRDF(origStmts, rdfFile);

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(rdfFile);
        parser.parse(reader, baseURI);
        if(origStmts.equals(processedStmts)){
            assert(true);
        }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }
}
```

When you set the collector for the parser above, it simply collects any statements that the parser ingests. After doing this, you can compare the collector with origStmts. This wasn't immediately obvious, but is really useful after finding it!

Comment: This will work fine, but as a tip: it can be done shorter and more convenient, by using this: `Model processedStmts = Rio.parse(reader, baseURI, RDFFormat.RDFXML);`

Comment: I should also point out that using `Model.equals` to compare two RDF models will not always give the expected result: if your RDF model contains blank nodes, this will fail, despite the models being essentially identical. You should be using [ModelUtil.equals](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/model/util/ModelUtil.html) instead.